# What exactly are join strategies?

Tags: sql, join

I am currently reading on how the Query Optimizer works and I keep encountering the phrase 'join strategies', and that the Query Optimizer includes it in cost computation.

What exactly are join strategies? Any examples?

For a query with a single join, does that mean there are more than one possible 'join strategies' for that query? Or does this only apply to queries with multiple joins?

And when we are talking about join strategies for queries having multiple joins, how would that exactly work?

I always thought when solving multiple joins, you solve the first join first, then the result set of that will be joined to the next join, so on and so forth. Do join strategies actually change up the order? Wouldn't that affect the results returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > I always thought when solving multiple joins, you solve the first join first, then the result set of that will be joined to the next join, so on and so forth. Do join strategies actually change up the order? Wouldn't that affect the results returned?

No - joining and filtering in a different order won't change the result. But it can affect the speed of the result, and that's why the order is often changed internally

Are you using SQL Server? Press CTRL-L to see the query plan. To a certain extent this is a product specific answer but...

To me a 'join strategy' is how the joins will be satisfied.

For example you might use a hash join or a loop join

You might filter data before or after the join

The query planner will usually rearrange joins and filters to produce what it thinks will be the quickest result. That often means filtering early and evaluating joins that produce fewer rows as early as possible.

For example if you are joining large tables `A` and `B`, with a where filter on both tables `A` and `B`, and the query planner thinks that applying the filter will reduce the number of records on table `A`, but not table `B`, then it is likely to *first* filter table A to get a reduced number of records, then it might use a loop join (which is most efficient when joining a large table to a small table) to join the filtered records from A to the larger number of records in `B`.

The order of joins in your submitted SQL Statement is irrelevant to the order they are actually performed in the plan... (unless you use the `ordered` hint in Oracle), and you still get the same answer

Any filter in your `where` clause might be applied before or after a join (usually before if at all possible) and you'll still get the same answer

So a join strategy is the approach taken to turn 'declarative' SQL statement (this is *what* I want) into an actual bunch of physical steps to produce it (filter this table then join with that table etc.)